# Amazon S3 JSON File - Access Denied

Tags: json, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an SPA application in Angular and have enabled write to JSON files by enabling PUT in the CORS Config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I can create a JSON file via PUT and then do a GET to see the file I have created, from the browser window. However, when downloading the created JSON file via the Online S3 console or CloudBerry, I get an "access denied" even though I am using the root account with the secret key. The error message looks like this:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>876213549363694A</RequestId>
<HostId>
ePMtRfoLm7zUrjYwSG6aIWIBeIwWI0Ajiq+LSUqylKofhdIIbSm5LfncoS0ZvxcC
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3's permission system is a bit [interesting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html). S3 tracks ownership information for objects in buckets as well as buckets themselves - objects CAN have a different owner than the bucket they belong to, and if the owners are different you must have permission from BOTH of them to access the object - even if you're the owner of the bucket!

You're uploading the object anonymously, so the object ends up owned by the anonymous user. You (the owner of the bucket) have given permission for the anonymous user to read objects from your bucket, and the object is owned by the anonymous user, so unauthenticated GET calls work. However, the anonymous user who performed the upload has NOT given you (the bucket owner) permission to read the object, so calls authenticated using your credentials are rejected... Bizarre.

The quickest way out of this situation is to include an "x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control" header on your PUT request. This grants the owner of the bucket (you) full control to read, write, or delete the object even though it's still "owned" by the anonymous user. You may want to consider making this header required on all anonymous PUT requests in the bucket policy as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#grant-putobject-conditionally-1).

---

Adding an example:

```
$http.put("/path", jsonData, {
                    headers: { 'x-amz-acl': 'bucket-owner-full-control' }
                    }
);
```